# How can I pass value to my component on `onBlur` event of PrimeNG autocomplete textbox?

Tags: angular, angular5, primeng, angular4-forms

I am using PrimeNG [autocomplete](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/autocomplete) textbox. How can I send value to my component on `onBlur` event ?

**Template**

```
<p-autoComplete (ngModelChange)="orguser.userid = $target.value" 
class="ui-autocomplete autocomplete" [suggestions]="results" 
(completeMethod)="search($event)" (onSelect)="onSelect($event)" 
(onBlur)="onBlur($event)" field="userid"></p-autoComplete>
```

**Component**

```
onBlur(value) {    
    console.log(value); // I have tried a number of things like value.target etc    
  }
```

`(onBlur)="onBlur(orguser.userid )"` also does not work

Comment: you mean $event.target.value not value.target

Comment: actually the name of the parameter is value and I am passing `$event` so its ` $event.target` event

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `(onBlur)="onBlur($event)"` try this :

```
onBlur(event) {
  console.log(event.target.value);
}
```

You should get what you typed with your keyboard.

And with

```
onSelect(value) {
  console.log(value);
}
```

you will have the selected item value.

See [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h5hgij)

Comment: I had the same problem, this worked for me, thanks :)